# Sum values in ssrs with excluding one field

Tags: reporting-services, conditional-statements

I have a report and need to Sum values from Input_Type (they are Actuals, Adjustment, Estimate, Forecast and Budget, but I need to exclude Budget).

If I use this condition, I get an error.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!INPUT_TYPE.Value = "Actuals" + Fields!INPUT_TYPE.Value = "Adjustment" + Fields!INPUT_TYPE.Value = "Estimate" + Fields!INPUT_TYPE.Value = "Forecast",Fields!VALUE.Value,  0), "GlobalReport")
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Change the **+** to **OR**.

Answer (score 1):

Try the reverse of what you're attempting to write.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!INPUT_TYPE.Value = "Budget", 0, Fields!VALUE.Value), "GlobalReport")
```